# How does Eclipse web service explorer work?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, cxf

Provided a WSDL I create a dynamic web service client. What I want is to expose the methods and the types of the parameters those methods have and test the code from a webpage. Bare in mind that the client is dynamic, so what I have to build must me able to work with different WSDLs.

What I want to do is what the Eclipse web service explorer does for testing a web service client from the provided user interface. How does it find the methods and the parameters? Does it parse the WSDL? I've searched for the source code, but I couldn't find anything relevant. I don't even know where to begin.
What I want is suggestions and some guidance of what I have to build, what is already provided out there (that I'm not aware obviously) and a place to begin. I'm not asking for code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially creating a generic web services client would involve the following:

1. Analyse the WSDL for service definitions i.e. the method names and their definitions. Remember your WSDL defines your service.
2. Analyse any XSD (embedded or linked) to retrieve the datatypes of the parameters etc.

As a suggestion why not look at the SOAP UI project which is really great as a generic web service test client. As it is open source you might be able to learn how they do it. Go have a look at the project [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/)

Also go look at the Apache CXF framework. This framework will allow you to easily create a webservice client. See this tutorial for more information: [how to create a client in CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html). CXF is also usable via javascript so it might be what you are looking for see this [link](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/javascript-clients.html)

I would suggest that you try leveraging these tools before you try to invent one yourself as parsing WSDL's and XSD while NOT difficult to parse it going to take a substantial programming effort. CXF already has this covered for you if I read your question right.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Could I be a little greedy and take a little bit further? Let's say I have a program that that takes as a parameter a wsdl. The goal of this program is to invoke the web service methods (as a client) without any prior knowledge about it. I've read about dynamic clients with cxf, and about reflection in java for loading the class without knowing it's name (pass it as a parameter in runtime). But how can I invoke the right method, and more importantly how can I pass the right parameters to that method. That is my goal. The source code link you provided is great.

Comment: Reinventing the wheel by parsing the wsdl as you stated is not the way to go. I couldn't agree more.

Comment: Well if a WSDL exposes 15 methods which one is right? You would probably need to create a interface which displays these options for the user to see and fill in. This is not something that you can automate completely unless you knew more or less what you were looking for. Is this going to be a generic WS client like Soap UI etc?

Comment: Yes a truly generic ws client that will show to the user the methods and the parameters that each method takes (either simple or complex objects).

Comment: My suggestion is to use SOAP UI and see how they do it. Then plan how to achieve it on the web.

Comment: Yes I will do that, although going through all that code and deciding what is relevant and what is not, is not an easy task. Doesn't cxf offers some functionality on that field? I mean when the stubs are generated, the code includes a class containing the main method that invokes the methods with some test parameters. To be able to do that, a mapping must be present. Isn't there a way to use that information?

Comment: I wish I had more answers. Maybe join the apache cxf mailing list and ask questions there directly to the developers?

Comment: Yep that's my next move. I just thought that I was just missing something and it would be, if not trivial, something more common. I've already upvoted, but I will keep it open if something else comes up. Although I think you will get the bounty. You really helped, thank you.